# Tensorflow, what does from_logits = True or False mean in sparse_categorical_crossentropy of Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function, cross-entropy

In Tensorflow 2.0,
there is a loss function called

```
tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, targets, from_logits = False)
```

Can I ask you what are the differences between setting from_logits = True or False?
My guess was that when incoming values are logits, you set from_logits = True, and if incoming values are probabilities(output by softmax etc.) then you just set from_logits = False (which is a default setting).

But why? loss is just some calculation. Why does it need to differ by its incoming values?
I also saw in google's tensorflow tutorial
https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/sequences/text_generation
that it doesnt set from_logits = True even if incoming values of the last layer are logits.
Here is the code

```
@tf.function
def train_step(inp, target):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(inp)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(target, predictions))
  grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

  return loss
```

where the model is

```
 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, 
                              batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(rnn_units, 
                        return_sequences=True, 
                        stateful=True, 
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
  ])
```

which does not have the last layer of softmax.
(Also, in another part of the tutorial, it set from_logits = True)

So, doesn't it matter whether I set it True or not?

Comment: It seems that they already added the `from_logits=True` in the code.

Comment: This might help you understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253841/from-logits-true-and-from-logits-false-get-different-training-result-for-tf-loss

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The post Deepak mentioned has some math background.

But for simplicity, from_logits=True means the input to crossEntropy layer is normal tensor/logits, while if from_logits=False, means the input is a probability and usually you should have some softmax activation in your last layer.