# How is Tensorflow SparseCategoricalCrossentropy is Impelemented?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am working on a weighted version of `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`. right now my implementation is converting y_true to one hot form and calculates the cross entropy then multiplies it with a weight matrix. I get the same output between my implementation and `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` when weights are all 1 however my problem is with one hot encoding. I have a lot of classes (32+bg) and when using one hot encoding I run out of memory for large images/batch sizes which does not happen with `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`. I am trying to figure out how is the built in one implemented (is there a way to avoid one hot encoding etc.). How is the built in one implemented or where is it implemented looking at [1] it is probably implemented on the native side but I can not find it?

[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L692

Comment: check this myb helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787897/how-does-tensorflow-sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SparseCategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) documentation has a "View Source on GitHub" tab you can click on. This will show you the implementation. Doing this leads us to [line 666](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L666-L739) of `tensorflow.python.keras.losses`. We can see from the class definition that it wraps a function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` which is defined on [line 4867](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4867) of `tensorflow.keras.backend`. We can see at the bottom of the function definition this is a wrapper around `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` and this function definition can be found in [tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L4181). At the bottom of this function definition, we can see it is a wrapper around `gen_nn_ops.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.  If you look for `gen_nn_ops`, you won't find it. It is the name of the `*.so` file that python imports to run tensorflow's C++ op code. So what we are really looking for is a sparse softmax C++ kernel, which can be found in [tensorflow.core.kernels.sparse_xent_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dec8e0b11f4f87693b67e125e67dfbc68d26c205/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_xent_op.cc#L51). This op calls a functor which calls a method `SparseXentEigenImpl` whose implementation can be found in the [corresponding header file, sparse_xent_op.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dec8e0b11f4f87693b67e125e67dfbc68d26c205/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_xent_op.h#L47). And starting on line 47 of that file you can see how they create the sparse loss.

```cpp
// Generator for calculation of the sparse Xent loss.
// This generator takes the logits, the sum of the exponentiated
// logits, and the label indices.  For each minibatch entry, ignoring
// the batch index b, it calculates:
//
//   loss[j] = (log(sum_exp_logits) - logits[j]) * 1{ j == label }
//
// for j = 0 .. num_classes.  This value must be summed over all j for
// the final loss.
```

And on [line 224](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dec8e0b11f4f87693b67e125e67dfbc68d26c205/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_xent_op.h#L224) there is a comment of outlining the loss calculation formula.

```cpp
//  sum(-labels *
//     ((logits - max_logits) - log(sum(exp(logits - max_logits)))))
//  along classes
```

Not sure if this helps you create your weighted op, but this is how sparse xent is calculated in tensorflow.

**Edit**:
There also is a method [`tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits?hl=ko). Not sure if that will work with your sparsity requirement, but will probably work better than trying to implement something yourself.