Tensorflow: INVALID_ARGUMENT: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,2] and labels shape [64]
I'm using tensorflow to test the accuracy of a dataset. You can find my full code as well as the dataset here
I'm still learning Machine Learning and there are a lot of things that are giving me a headache. For example why in this scenario when I compile model using "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
# Since the labels are not one-hot encoded, we use the Sparse Categorical Crossentropy Loss
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="sgd",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

there is an error:
INVALID_ARGUMENT: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,2] and labels shape [64]
However, after spending hours looking at the codes and fixing each line hopelessly. Finally it works! By changing loss="categorical_crossentropy"
# Since the labels are not one-hot encoded, we use the Sparse Categorical Crossentropy Loss
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="sgd",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

I could really use an explanation right now and I'll be much in appreciation!

You are performing one hot encoding of the labels. Use categorical_cross_entropy when your labels are one hot encoded, and use sparse_categorical_cross_entropy when your labels aren't one hot encoded. Because the sparse_categorical_cross_entropy tends to do the one hot conversion internally and then call categorical_cross_entropy;
Additionally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787897/how-does-tensorflow-sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-work
