# from_logits=True but loss is 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning tensorflow and want to relate tensorflow implementation with Mathematics.

From my knowledge, mathematical cross entropy requires the sum of its input to be 1. In the following code, `y_true` is a valid input while `y_pred` is not a Mathematically valid input:

```
y_true = [[0, 1]]
y_pred = [[1.0, 20.0]]
print(tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False).call(y_true, y_pred))
print(tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True).call(y_true, y_pred))
```

Gives:

```
tf.Tensor([0.04879016], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Please find the gist [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u2OXwED03gtbzFbd6nTTlYDwdPXU77LO?usp=sharing).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145774/746461) says:

> if from_logits=False, means the input is a probability

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64532515/746461) says:

> `from_logits=True` means the input to crossEntropy layer is normal
> tensor/logits

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50511692/746461) says:

> "Another name for `raw_predictions` in the above code is `logit`

`from_logits`, I guess, means the input is `raw_predictions`.

Since my input are not probability, I set `from_logits=True`, but the result I get is 0.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross entropy between labels `[[0, 1]]` and logits `[[1, 20]]` should be a value very close to 0 (and some outputs might represent it as zero due to floating point imprecision). Represented as probabilities, these logits would be approximately `[[0.000000005, 1]]`. Notice how close these probabilities are to the labels. The cross entropy should therefore be very low.

As OP points out in their question, `from_logits=True` should be used when operating on unscaled outputs. Practically speaking, `from_logits=True` is used if operating on outputs *before* softmax. Softmax maps unscaled outputs to probabilities. To compute cross entropy of those probabilities, `from_logits=False` should be used.

Here is an example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 1]], "float32")
y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 20]], "float32")

ce_logits_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
ce_probs_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

print(ce_logits_fn(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)

print(ce_probs_fn(y_true, tf.nn.softmax(y_pred)))
# tf.Tensor(1.1920929e-07, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Try with predictions closer together. In the example above, the value of the correct class is much higher than the incorrect class, so cross entropy will be low.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 1]], "float32")
y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor([[5, 7]], "float32")

ce_logits_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
ce_probs_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

print(ce_logits_fn(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor(0.12692805, shape=(), dtype=float32)

print(ce_probs_fn(y_true, tf.nn.softmax(y_pred)))
# tf.Tensor(0.126928, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: That clarifies a lot, thanks! I find `ce_logits_fn(y_true, tf.nn.softmax(y_pred))` outputs a different result. I guess softmax of softmax is not idempotent. If the input so happens  to be like [0.1,0.9], should I set `from_logits=True`? Should I check each input and if any input doesn't look like probability, I assume the inputs didn't go through softmax?

Comment: Well, my real concern is that is it ok to alway turn on `from_logits=True`? In case my model already have a softmax layer, does keeping  `from_logits=True` affect training?

Comment: Because your model is giving probabilities, you should use `from_logits=False`. Newer versions (not sure since when) of `tf.keras` will implicitly [use the logits if they are available](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4835-L4839). Interesting point that softmax of probabilities does not return the same values... I would be very curious to know why.

Comment: If you were to use `from_logits=True` on probabilities, then your loss would be wrong, and your model would not learn correctly.